# In ESP IDF framework, restrict write operation on holding register

Tags: esp-idf

I am developing Modbus Slave Application with read and write access to multiple registers. The application requirement is, Master should be able to read all the registers in one go. (Say 100 registers at a time). So I have defined "reg_area.type" as "MB_PARAM_HOLDING".
In this case, access is given to all the registers to be Read & Write. I need to have some registers to be Read-only access. Here I can use "reg_area.type" as "MB_PARAM_INPUT " but, I can not read all the registers in the one Go. I have to read Holding Registers and again I have to read Input Registers.

So, how can I restrict write operations to specific Holding Registers?

I am currently using below link example to create Modbus Slave

https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/v4.1/examples/protocols/modbus/serial/mb_slave/main/slave.c